# Grouping options together in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two selections. Which are IT and Management. Both of them has one of the same option. How can I group them together?

How can I do that? I actually new in Jquery

As you can see the IT and Management had both the same option which is Analyst. How should I code to ensure that the Analyst is declared one time but can be used in both IT and Mangement

***Code:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }

    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select2').html(options);
  });

  $("#select1").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="3"></option>
  <option value="1">IT</option>
  <option value="2">Management</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="3"></option>
  <option value="1">Programmer</option>
  <option value="1">Technician</option>
  <option value="1">Analyst</option>
  <option value="2">HR</option>
  <option value="2">Secretary</option>
  <option value="2">Analyst</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean by grouping together? do you want to use a `optgroup`?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that if you select the blank option (3) on `select1`, the blank option is selected on `select2`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (even after the edit). As it is, you can select any option from both dropdowns, which seems to fit your requirement that Analyst can be selected for IT or Management. Is that not the behavior you want? If so, what is the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: I just want to know is it possible to declare the Analyze option once but they may use in two option which is in Management and IT

Comment: No, unless you are building the `<option>` elements dynamically from a backend data source or JavaScript array.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're trying to do now. It's not exactly possible the way you have it set up now, but I'll give you an example of another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want different options to be populated in the second dropdown, depending on the selection in the first. And, you want to use the "same" option (Analyst) in both the first and second box. Here's one way you could do it:

**HTML**

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="it">IT</option>
    <option value="management">Management</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <!-- options will be loaded dynamically -->
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// hashtable of all roles
// (keys could be strings or ints, depending on your style and data)
var roles = {};
roles['code'] = 'Programmer';
roles['tech'] = 'Technician';
roles['analyst'] = 'Analyst';
roles['hr'] = 'HR';
roles['secretary'] = 'Secretary';
roles['boss'] = 'Boss';

// store the keys we want for each option group
var groups = {};
groups['it'] = ['code', 'tech', 'analyst'];
groups['management'] = ['hr', 'secretary', 'analyst'];

function changeOptionGroup(groupKey) {
    // clear out the current options
    $("#select2").empty();

    // load the correct ones
    groups[groupKey].forEach(function (value, index) {
        $("#select2").append($("<option />")
            .val(value)
            .text(roles[value]));
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // when the first box changes, update the second
    $('#select1').change(function () {
        changeOptionGroup($(this).val());
    });

    // fire on page load
    $('#select1').change();
});
```

**Explanation**

1. First, we populate `roles` with all of the possible options we want to use in the second box. Each one is stored with a key and a value.
2. Then, we can make a `groups` object and store an array of the keys we want to see in each group. The group has a key, too - note how I made the keys here (`it` and `management`) the same as the values of the options in the `select1` dropdown. That'll be useful in a minute.
3. The `changeOptionGroup()` function takes a `groupKey` parameter, clears out the second box, and then uses a loop to add the correct options to the second box depending on the group we've selected. `groups[groupKey]` accesses the `groups` object and retrieves the array of role keys we want. `.text(roles[value])` looks up a specific role in the `roles` object (`value` is provided by the loop).
4. Finally, we can wire all this up in `.ready()`. This is pretty simple: just a event binding to `.change()` to call `changeOptionGroup` with the currently selected option's `value` passed in. We also need to fire the event on page load (otherwise, it won't work until the first time the user changes the selection).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/do9kq54r/2/

Comment: This certainly isn't the only way to do it (and you could definitely optimize it), but hopefully this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Okay I understand. Thanks a lot..then how can I make the second selection and first selection empty when I refresh the browser?

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. I'm sure you already figured it out, but if you want the selects to be empty on pageload, you could just hardcode an empty option element in each one. You'd want an extra check inside of `changeOptionGroup` so that if that empty option is select again in the first dropdown, it clears out the second but doesn't try to load any options into it. Also, you could get rid of the call to fire `.change()`, too.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, would you mind accepting it by clicking the big checkmark? A vote up would be appreciated too. :)